# Best data structure for full text search in SQL Server 2014

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2014

The following is a contrived simplified example:

```
USE Test;

IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.Books', 'U') IS NOT NULL
      DROP TABLE dbo.Books; 

IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.Authors', 'U') IS NOT NULL
      DROP TABLE dbo.Authors; 

CREATE TABLE dbo.Authors
(
        AuthorId BIGINT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1), 
        AuthorName NVARCHAR(MAX) NOT NULL   
)

CREATE TABLE dbo.Books
(
        BookId BIGINT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1), 
        BookTitle NVARCHAR(MAX) NOT NULL,   
        FirstAuthorId BIGINT NOT NULL,
        CONSTRAINT [FK_BookToFirstAuthor_Authors] FOREIGN KEY([FirstAuthorId]) REFERENCES Authors([AuthorId])
)
```

Would this be an efficient enough structure to full text search (e.g. via `CONTAINS`) in `BookTitle` and (First)`AuthorName`?

Or would something like this be better:

```
CREATE TABLE Books
(
    BookId BIGINT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1), 
    BookTitle NVARCHAR(MAX) NOT NULL,   
    FirstAuthorId BIGINT NOT NULL,
    FirstAuthorName NVARCHAR(MAX) NOT NULL, 
    CONSTRAINT [FK_BookToFirstAuthor_Authors] FOREIGN KEY([FirstAuthorId]) REFERENCES Authors([AuthorId])
)
```

Please note that I see Book rows like immutable 'objects'. Any feedback would be very much appreciated. Many thanks.

Comment: Personaly, I would keep the tables normalized as in the first example (the second example contains reference to `Authors` table as well as `FirstAuthorName` which seems redundant). To do a full text search over multiple tables I would create an indexed view that joins both tables and create a full text index on all needed columns in that view. Depends on your individual case though.

Comment: Yeah a view is another option. Thanks for your comment.